# rownumbers is not working in jsgrid, want to show total numbers of records (row)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsgrid

**rownumbers is not working in jsgrid, want to show total numbers of records (row).I want to show it in rightside of pagination data.**

```
$("#jsgrid").jsGrid({
    autoload: true,
    width: "100%",
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    paging: true,
    multiselect:true,
    pageSize: 3,
    pageButtonCount: 2,
    sorting: true,
    rownumbers:true,
    controller: {
        loadData: function() {
            return data;
        }
    },
});
```

[image]
[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k9935wn3/278/)

Comment: Please, be correct in the tags. You mark jqGrid, but actually you use jsgrid, which is very difficult product. Please correct the tags to the right product you use.

Comment: typing mistake..

Comment: Fixed, in addition bracket and indentation corrected

Comment: I don't see any `rownumbers` parameter in the [documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/), you may need `pageFormat`, using `{itemCount}` to display the number of items:

```
$("#jsgrid").jsGrid({
    /* Other parameters here */
    pagerFormat: "Pages: {first} {prev} {pages} {next} {last} &nbsp;&nbsp; {pageIndex} of {pageCount} Total rows: {itemCount}"
});
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. @nicolas-cami

Comment: when results/items are less than page size then its not displaying